# Ubuntu: Backing up network files with duplicity?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, terminal, amazon-s3, duplicity

I just installed Duplicity on Ubuntu and got everything working. However, when I try to backup a network samba-connected windows drive, The following occurs:

```
Backup source directory /smb:/windowscomputer/harddrive/folder does not exist.
```

Here's how it's formatted in my backup.sh script:

```
duplicity --full-if-older-than 14D --encrypt-key=XXXXXXX --sign-key=XXXXXXX smb://windowscomputer/harddrive/folder s3+http://myS3BUCKET
```

What can I do to make this work? I'm kinda stuck right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this after mounting the Samba (windows) drive properly.

Answer Answered :)